# Ruby on Rails: How to override the 'show' route of a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I have a route that looks like this:

```
resources :posts
```

I want to override the 'show' action so that I can display a url like this:

```
posts/:id/:slug
```

I am currently able to do this by adding a custom `match` route:

```
resources :posts
match 'posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show'
```

However, when I use the `link_to` helper, it does not use my custom show route.

```
<%= link_to 'show', post %>  # renders /posts/123
```

How can I define my show route so that I can still use the `link_to` helper?

**Update:** As you can read in the following answers, you can override the route to the 'show' action, but it's probably more work than it's worth. It's easier to just create a custom route:

```
# config/routes.rb
match 'posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show', as: 'post_seo'

# app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= link_to post.title, post_seo_path(post.id, post.slug) %>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have two routes which point to `posts#show` (you should be able to confirm this by running `rake routes`), and your link is using the wrong one.

When you call `link_to('show', post)` the URL of the link is generated by calling `url_for(post)` which (eventually, after passing through several other methods on the way) calls `post_path(post)`.  Since the route to `posts#show` that was created by your call to `resources(:posts)` is named `post`, that is the route that `post_path` generates.

You also currently have inconsistent routes for the show, update and destroy actions which will probably cause you problems later on.

You can fix this by changing your routes to the following:

```
resources :posts, :except => ['show', 'update', 'destroy']
get    'posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show', :as => 'post'
put    'posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#update'
delete 'posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#destroy'
```

Unfortunately you still can't use `link_to('show', post)` just yet, because it relies on being able to use `post.to_param` as the single argument needed to build a path to a post. Your custom route requires *two* arguments, an `id` and a `slug`.  So now your link code will need to look like this:

```
link_to 'show', post_path(post.id, post.slug)
```

You can get around that problem by defining your own `post_path` and `post_url` helpers in `app/helpers/posts_helper.rb`:

```
module PostsHelper
  def post_path(post, options={})
    post_url(post, options.merge(:only_path => true))
  end

  def post_url(post, options={})
    url_for(options.merge(:controller => 'posts', :action => 'show',
                          :id => post.id, :slug => post.slug))
  end
end
```

Which means we're finally able to use:

```
link_to 'show', post
```

---

If that all seems like too much work, a common alternative is to use URLs that look more like `posts/:id-:slug`, in which case you can stick with the standard RESTful routes and just override the `to_param` method in your `Post` class:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug}"
end
```

You'll also need to do a little bit of work splitting up `params[:id]` into an ID and a slug before you can look up the relevant instance in your show, edit, update and destroy controller actions.

Comment: the quick fix is to just reverse the order of the original routes.

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :posts, except: :show do
    get ":slug" => :show, as: "", on: :member
end
```

and define helper

```
  def post_path post
     "/posts/#{post.id}/#{post.slug}"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

db/migrate/add_slug_to_articles.rb

```
add_column :articles, :slug, :string
add_index :articles, :slug
```

models/article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record?
  end
end
```

## Or...

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :history
end
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id