# How to customize the categories and sub categories in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Help!

It is impossible to realize the right category and subcategory, please help me.

My code

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  has_many  :scategories, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

scategory.rb

```
class Scategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :category
  has_many   :posts, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

post.rb

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base  

    belongs_to    :scategory
    belongs_to    :user

  end
```

_post.html.haml

```
.column4.post-block.item
  / Отложенная загрузка картинок "lazy: true" (исправить баг)
  = link_to image_tag(post.post_cover.url(:medium)), post
  .title
    = link_to truncate(post.title, :length => 70), category_scategory_post_url(category_id: @category.slug, scategory_id: @scategory.slug, id: @post.slug)
  -#
    .description
      = truncate(post.description, :length => 70)
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :scategories do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
```

Can not find a method of slug, how to properly do?

Comment: can you share  `posts_controller`'s show (or equivalent) method?

Comment: Yes. `def index
    pub = params[:published] == "false" ? false : true
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page]).order('created_at DESC').where(published: pub)
    @bposts = Bpost.order('created_at DESC').all.limit(4) 
  end`

Comment: no, i mean single post. like this `@post = @posts.find(x)` or `@post = Post.find(x)`

Comment: `@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0):

change it  to `@post = Post.friendly.find_by_slug(params[:slug])`.

also change your category and scategory controller like above.

p.s. before these check you've `permit`ted `:slug` attribute.

p.p.s. also consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11571314/4481312) for editing routes